Understanding 優等生と言われても通る気がするけど
I need help understanding 優等生と言われても通る気がするけど from this image:

I am not sure who is the subject for 言われる. The speaker or Fujinami?
Also, I uncertain about the meaning of 通る. I think it corresponds to this sense:

⓬ 自分の主義や主張をどこまでも貫いて、受け入れられる。
「原告の主張が━」
「そんなわがままは━・らない」

according to 明鏡国語辞典. So 優等生と言われても通る means 優等生と言われてもその主張が通る. Is that right?

The subject for 言われる is either the speaker himself or "generic you/someone". The implied subject of 通る is either Fujinami or the information (that she is a 優等生).
If the subject of 通る is her, this 15th definition from 明鏡国語辞典 is closer:

世間に認められて通用する。
「彼は名だたる頑固者で通っている」「世間では独身で通っている」「あの親子は姉妹としても十分通る」「名の通った店」

The English translation would be "to pass (as ～)" or "to be (widely) recognized (as ～)".

優等生と言われても通る気がする。
Even if [I/someone] was told that she is a diligent student, I feel [she/it] would pass as such.

